# What is the difference between json.Marshal and json.MarshalIndent using Go?

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I would like to get an output of a CF command in JSON format but I am not sure what to use either `json.Marshal` or `json.MarshalIndent`.

The output I need is like this:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
     ....
    "keyn": "valuen",
}
```

This is the old example but it is not the desired output:

```
cmd.ui.Say(terminal.EntityNameColor(T("User-Provided:")))   
  for _, key := range keys {        
         // cmd.ui.Say("%s: %v", key, envVars[key])
         here needed a new one with json.marshalIdent
 }
```

I never used go so I really do not know which one to use and how.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the doc is pretty clear on this. Both [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)
and [`json.MarshalIndent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent) produces a JSON text result (in the form of a `[]byte`), but while the former does a compact output without indentation, the latter applies (somewhat customizable) indent. Quoting from doc of `json.MarshalIndent()`:

> MarshalIndent is like Marshal but applies Indent to format the output.

See this simple example:

```
type Entry struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
}

e := Entry{Key: "value"}
res, err := json.Marshal(e)
fmt.Println(string(res), err)

res, err = json.MarshalIndent(e, "", "  ")
fmt.Println(string(res), err)
```

The output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ASeuLtLWa0)):

```
{"key":"value"} <nil>
{
  "key": "value"
} <nil>
```

There is also [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder):

```
type Entry struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
}
e := Entry{Key: "value"}

enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
if err := enc.Encode(e); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

enc.SetIndent("", "  ")
if err := enc.Encode(e); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v1s9YkwA8w)):

```
{"key":"value"}
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

Comment: thank a lot but I have another problem, i will have more than one key and value and I would like to use json.marshalIdent inside a loop, can you modify the code ?

Comment: @Foudel If you have a specific problem, include that in the question. I don't know your code. Also note that you can pass slices or structs that contain slices to `json.Marshal()`, and they will be properly marshaled into JSON arrays. You don't need to do that "manually".

Comment: have changed the code actually i am never used go I need only this small modif once forever.

Comment: @Foudel And what do you want the output to be? A series of (independent) JSON objects, or a JSON array of key-value pairs?

Comment: json array of key-values because it is needed to map to values to another keys which are the same , the whole process is that i will get those values and from one CF APP and then copy them to the keys of a new CF APP

Comment: @Foudel Then simply build a slice inside the loop (e.g. using the builtin `append()` function), then after the `for` loop pass the slice to `json.MarshalIndent()`.